# What does $\delta L$ mean in variation calculus?

Tags: notation, lagrange-multiplier

What does $\delta L(x,x')$ mean in variation calculus and Lagrangian mechanics? How is it different from the derivative? What does it mean to take $\delta$ of an action?

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Gateaux Variation or [Gateaux Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative). It's a higher-level analogue of the derivative, but you are "taking the derivative" of a functional instead of a function. There are theorems in the Calculus of Variations that show you get extremals of $L$ when $\delta L=0,$ at least in many cases.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  If you don't mind, I want to ask a little bit further. After reading what you refer, it seems to me that the Gateaux Variation is a directional derivative including x'(t), and not just x(t) itself of a functional F(x,x'). When you say $\delta L$=0, do you mean $\delta L$ =0 for all directions, all along the parametrization  a curve or any manifold? You don't have to answer if my question is confusing.

Comment: Sure! Let's suppose we're trying to find a geodesic (shortest path). The integral calculates the length of the path. We assume that if we are on the shortest path, the integral will be a minimum. So, we "take the derivative" of the integral, and set it equal to zero. At that point, we are allowing any path $y(x),$ along with its derivative, to show up in the integral. So yes, we are setting $\delta L=0$ along all possible paths, and letting the resulting equation (typically the Euler-Lagrange equation) to find that minimum. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Tank you. I know about the Euler Lagrange equation and how it is derived. I know also that ELE is a necessary condition.  But $\delta L$ =0 seems to give a different equation than the ELE. I wonder how $\delta L$ and ELE are related?

Comment: Under some conditions, $\delta L=0$ yields the ELE. Under other conditions, you can have more complicated equations (which, in turn, simplify to ELE if you re-introduce the right conditions). Yes, ELE is a necessary condition for an extremal. There are sufficient conditions as well in some cases like convex optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer has been very helpful.